# Observable<Observable<T>> to Observable<T> rxswift

Tags: swift, rx-swift

Hi I am having hard time trying to figure this out.
There is some bunch of other problem.

Can anyone help me making `Observable<[Observable<CellModel>]` to `Observable<[CellModel]>?`

the outcome for the `request(categoryId: $0)` was `Observable<[Observable<CellModel>?]>`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSber.png)

```
  selectCategory
        .do(onNext: { _ in output.cells.onNext([.init(cellID: kSkeletonTableID)]) })
        .flatMap { [unowned self] in request(categoryId: $0) }
       // .showIndicator()
        .trackError(errorTracker)
        .compactMap {
            var cellModel:[CellModel] = $0.flatMap { $0 }
            return cellModel
        }
        .bind(to: output.cells)
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Answer (score 1):

That's a pretty tortured type that you are returning from your `request(categoryId:)`. The real fix is there. However, the answer to this question is:

```
selectCategory
    .do(onNext: { _ in output.cells.onNext([.init(cellID: kSkeletonTableID)]) })
    .flatMap { request(categoryId: $0).flatMap { Observable.combineLatest($0.compactMap { $0 }) } }
    // .showIndicator()
    .trackError(errorTracker)
    .bind(to: output.cells)
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

You might want to consider one of the other variations of flatMap depending on the expected output. See this article for details: [RxSwift's Many Faces of FlatMap](https://danielt1263.medium.com/rxswifts-many-faces-of-flatmap-5764e6c2018c)

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer!  I know returning the value Observable<[Observable<CellModel>]> is not the best option! regarding that can you answer one more question that I am uploading now?  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68525265/rxswift-async-api-in-switch-array