# Rxswift Async api in switch array

Tags: swift, rx-swift

Hi I am uploading one more question since last question answer was so helpful !
so I am acutally trying to get `Observable<[CellModel>]>`
There is 10 different questionId in the array.
and I need to fetch additional data each in the same order.
and in result I ultimately want to have `Observable<[CellModel>]>`
but seems like without  `Observable.create`
api response get all mixed and if it takes longer, it will just returned 8 items instead of 10 items.
So I ended up getting item `Observable<[Observable<CellModel>?]`like this.
So I want to know if there is any diffrent way I can fetch addtional data without making additional Observable.create !
Thank you so much!

```
    private func request(categoryId: Int?) -> Observable<[Observable<CellModel>?]> {
            return .create { obs -> Disposable in
                self.requestAuthData(categoryId: categoryId)
                    .trackError(self.errorTracker)
                    .debug()
                    .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] model  in
                        guard let self = self else { return }
                        var cells: [Observable<CellModel>] = model.items.questions.map {
                            switch $0.cardType {
                            case .open:
                                if $0.type.isEssay {
                                    let info = $0
                                    return  Observable.create { [weak self] observer in
                                        self?.requestEssayData(question_id: info.id, info, completion: { (cellmodel) in
                                            observer.onNext(cellmodel)
                                            observer.onCompleted()
                                        })
                                        return Disposables.create()
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    let info = $0
                                    return  Observable.create { [weak self] observer in
                                        self?.requestMutipleAnswerData(question_id: info.id, info, completion: { (cellmodel) in
                                            observer.onNext(cellmodel)
                                            observer.onCompleted()
                                        })
                                        return Disposables.create()
                                    }
                                }
                            case .blind, .sample, .not_confirmed, .please_sign_in:
                                let info = $0
                                return  Observable.create { [weak self] observer in
                                    self?.requestMutipleAnswerData(question_id: info.id, info, completion: { (cellmodel) in
                                        observer.onNext(cellmodel)
                                        observer.onCompleted()
                                    })
                                    return Disposables.create()
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        cells.append( Observable.create { [weak self] observer in
                            observer.onNext( NewsTopScrollCellModel())
                            observer.onCompleted()
                            return Disposables.create()
                        })
                        obs.onNext(cells)
                        obs.onCompleted()
                    })
                return Disposables.create()
            }
        }



 private func requestEssayData(question_id: Int, _ item: QuestionInfo,  completion: @escaping (CellModel) -> Void) {
        let info = item
        Observable.zip(self.requestDetailData(question_id), self.requestTagData(question_id))
            .trackError(self.errorTracker)
            .share()
            .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] essay, tag in
                guard let self = self else { return }
                let noData: Bool = essay.items.totalCount == 0
                guard !noData else {
                    return  completion(EmptyCellViewModel(spacing: 0.5)) }
                completion(PremiumReviewEssayCellModel(item, companyID: self.companyID, essay: essay, tag: tag, delegate: self))
            })
            .disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
    }

private func requestDetailData(_ question_id: Int) -> Observable<EssayModel> {
    let params: [String: Any] = ["company_id": companyID, "question_id": question_id, "type": "text"]
    return Network
        .request("/apiapi~~~mightbe important1", parameters: params)
        .expectType(EssayModel.self)
}

private func  requestTagData(_ question_id: Int) -> Observable<TagData> {
    let params: [String: Any] = ["company_id": companyID, "question_id": question_id]
    return Network
        .request("/apiapi~~~mightbe important2", parameters: params)
        .expectType(TagData.self)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand the question a simplified version of what you want is something similar to:

```swift
Observable.just([1, 2, 3])
  .flatMap {
    Observable.zip($0.map(mapFunc))
  }

func mapFunc(a: Int) -> Observable<String> {
  return .just("\(a)")
}
```

So you start from an `Observable<[Int]>` then you map each value in the array to a new `Observable<String>` resulting in a `Observable<[Observable<String>]>`. By using `zip` you get the ordered behaviour and the `Observable<[String]>`.

Also, when you have such cases:

```
Observable.create { [weak self] observer in
    observer.onNext(NewsTopScrollCellModel())
    observer.onCompleted()
    return Disposables.create()
}
```

You can use `just` which is equivalent:

```
Observable.just(NewsTopScrollCellModel())
```

Comment: This is a good answer, except that it doesn't need to be `concat` which will serialize the requests. You could use `zip` instead which will start all the requests at the same time, but keep them in order for the array.

Comment: Thank you so much Fabio , Daniel!  I am learning so much from these answers!